# Derivative of a plot

Tags: plotting, differentials

I plotted a graph numerically, so I don't have a definition of the plotted function. Now I want to plot the derivative of this graph. Is there any way to do it in *Mathematica*? I have the following plot

[image]

Comment: How did you generate the plot, from a list of points?

Comment: @ John McGee yes you can say from order pairs

Comment: Have you seen `Interpolation[]`?

Comment: This [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApproximateFunctionsAndInterpolation.html) should contain all informations you'll need.

Answer (score 6):

if I understand you correctly you have the plot not the data.
you need to extract the data from the plot and then (as belisarius mentioned) use interpolation.

Example:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
data = Cases[p, Line[{x__}] :> x, -1];
d = D[Interpolation[data][x], x];
Plot[d, {x, 1, 2 \[Pi]}]
```